# JQueryUI DatePicker always displays todays date as selected even when selecting another date from it

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using AngularJS and JQuery UI DatePicker together in order to allow a user to select a date, of which I have two on the same page.

I have a custom directive which handles the interface between jQuery and AngularJS:

```
.directive('mydatepicker', function ($parse) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
                var ngModel = $parse(attrs.ngModel);
                $(function () {
                    element.datepicker({
                        showOn: "both",
                        changeYear: true,
                        changeMonth: true,
                        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                        onSelect: function (date, inst) {
                            scope.$apply(function (scope) {
                                ngModel.assign(scope, date);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        };
    })
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="mjaController.tempFiltering.fromDate" mydatepicker />
<input type="text" ng-model="mjaController.tempFiltering.toDate" mydatepicker />
```

Just to prove the value of the ngModel, I also print the value directly:

```
<pre>{{mjaController.tempFiltering.fromDate}}</pre>
<pre>{{mjaController.tempFiltering.toDate}}</pre>
```

However, it doesn't matter what value is in the ngModel, or what date I select directly from the datepicker: the datepicker **always** shows today's date as selected - **however the ngModel is updated to the selected date**.

[image: Datepicker always shows today as selected]

The datepicker works fine as standard jQuery, but once I tie it to an AngularJS directive, it seems to break it.

Please note, I copied the code pretty much exactly from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nnsese/xB6c2/26/) (skipping the maxDate and dateRange options), and it doesn't work, however it works great on that example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about angular. Anyway, I made some changes to the fiddle you post, hoping can suggest you the correct way to solve your problems.
Hope this helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/xB6c2/1155/

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
      
myApp.directive('myDatepickerfrom', function ($parse) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
        var ngModel = $parse(attrs.ngModel);
        $(function(){
            element.datepicker({
                showOn:"both",
                changeYear:true,
                changeMonth:true,
                dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'}).on('change', function(d,i){
                 $('#dp2').datepicker("option","minDate",$('#dp1').val());
                  scope.$apply(function(scope){
                        ngModel.assign(scope,$('#dp1').val());
                    });
                 
                });
        });
    }
}).directive('myDatepickerto', function ($parse) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
        var ngModel = $parse(attrs.ngModel);
        $(function(){
            element.datepicker({
                showOn:"both",
                changeYear:true,
                changeMonth:true,
                dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'}).on('change', function(){
                 $('#dp1').datepicker("option","maxDate",$('#dp2').val());
                  scope.$apply(function(scope){
                        ngModel.assign(scope,$('#dp2').val());
                    });
                });
        });
    }
});


function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.userInfo = {
        person: {
            firstDate: '2017-11-10',
            lastDate: '2017-11-20'
        }
    };
    
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

<input id="dp1" type="text" ng-model="userInfo.person.firstDate" name="firstDate" my-datepickerfrom/>

    <pre>{{userInfo.person.firstDate}}</pre>
    <hr />
    <input id="dp2" type="text" ng-model="userInfo.person.lastDate" name="lastDate" my-datepickerto/>

    <pre>{{userInfo.person.lastDate}}</pre>

</div>
```